# SQL Select categorias únicas ordenadas por popularidade

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando obter uma lista de categorias que estejam em uso e posteriormente ordená-las com base no número de registros para poder montar uma lista de categorias e usar no filtro do site. Então elas devem seguir essas restrições:

- Categorias únicas;
- Categorias que sejam usadas;
- Ordenar por popularidade (quanto mais registros ela possuir, mais no topo deve ficar);

Para isso possuo 2 tabelas, 1 com a relação de produtos e categorias:

```
relacao_categoria
id |  id_categoria | id_produto
```

E a outra com a lista das categorias

```
cadastro_categoria
id  | nome_categoria
```

No momento só não consegui fazer o select com base na popularidade, pois posteriormente preciso ordenar de acordo com o número de registros encontrados na tabela `cadastro_produto`

Esse é o meu sql:

```
$qry = sql("SELECT DISTINCT id_categoria FROM relacao_categoria");

// Processo para montar a array de id's com o resultado

$qry = sql("SELECT id, nome_categoria FROM cadastro_categoria WHERE id IN ($ids)");
```

Como posso fazer para que ao obter os resultados do 2º sql, os mesmos estejam em ordem de popularidade?

Comment: Tente SELECT count(*) as popularidade, id, nome_categoria from cadastro_categoria WHERE id in ( $ids) group by id, nome_categoria order by popularidade desc

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo apesar de também funcionar, a resposta do Juven_v foi mais objetiva e simples, recomendo dar uma olhada também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sugestão do comentário  do Reginaldo Rigo é uma boa solução. Opcionalmente você pode remover a primeira consulta sql `sql("SELECT DISTINCT id_categoria FROM relacao_categoria");` e fazer um inner join na segunda consulta.

Usando o [SQL editor do W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)
, a consulta ficaria assim (testei com duas tabelas com nomes diferentes, categories e products, mas que se encaixam na sua situação):

```
SELECT count(*) as popularidade, Categories.CategoryID, CategoryName 
from Categories, Products 
WHERE Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID group by
Categories.CategoryID, CategoryName order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Perfeito! Além de reduzir o número de `SELECT` (3 -> 1) simplificou bastante o processo! Muito obrigado